# Common label on python subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

From https://scipy-lectures.github.io/intro/matplotlib/auto_examples/plot_multiplot_ex.html

How can I put a common y-axis label on the 3 subplots (4,5 and 6)?

```
fig = pl.figure()
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.025, left=0.025, top = 0.975, right=0.975)

pl.subplot(2, 1, 1)
pl.xticks(()), pl.yticks(())

pl.subplot(2, 3, 4)
pl.xticks(())
pl.yticks(())

pl.subplot(2, 3, 5)
pl.xticks(())
pl.yticks(())

pl.subplot(2, 3, 6)
pl.xticks(())
pl.yticks(())

pl.show()
```

Comment: What is a `common y-axis label` in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `plt.subplots()` and then use numpy array indexing of the axes you want:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=3, figsize=(6, 6))
for ax in axes[-1, :]:
    ax.set_ylabel('My Ylabel')

fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Now you can use the `Axes` objects directly for plotting and customization, instead of the `plt` state-machine and interface ("explicit is better than implicit" and all that)